# How to solve Python dataframe boxplot column error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boxplot

I have a dataframe with columns names structured as follow:

| P_ID | CLASS | time | A1x | A1y | A1z | sec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1600 | A | 90426708196641 | 7.123 | 2.456 | -1.542 | 1 |

Now I am trying to use the function boxplot on the A1x,A1y,A1z columns using the following code (self._data_delimiters is used to get the A1x,A1y,A1z position with different dataframes, and it returns correctly the columns position):

`df.boxplot(column=list(df.columns[self._data_delimiters[0]: self._data_delimiters[1]]))`

But I get the following error:

KeyError: "None of [Index(['A1x', 'A1y', 'A1z'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Using `df.columns` it's possible to see that the columns are present in the dataframe:

Index(['P_ID', 'CLASS', 'time', 'A1x', 'A1y', 'A1z', 'sec'], dtype='object')

This is the part of the code where I use use boxplot:

```
# Boxplot Data
if header_type[len(header_type) - 1] == 'd':
   df.boxplot(column=list(df.columns[self._data_delimiters[1]: df.shape[1]-1]))
else:
 df.boxplot(column=list(df.columns[self._data_delimiters[0]: self._data_delimiters[1]]))

plt.savefig(os.path.join(Configurator(self.__cfg_path).get('settings', 'log_dir'), 'stats/data_boxplot.png'))
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Here simply I have two different way to retrieve the position of the columns depending if the data are the last columns in the dataframe or there are other information after them.

How can I solve this problem? Thank you for the reply and the help.

Comment: what is `self._data_delimiters` ??? can you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's a touple to get the starting and stop position for the data columns. For this dataframe it is (3,-1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the values in the dataframe might be more and that you've just added a single one. Here's a solution which could get you to draw a boxplot on your columns

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data = [{'P_ID':1600,'CLASS': 'A', 'time': 90426708196641, 'A1x': 7.123, 'A1y': 2.456, 'A1z': -1.542, 'sec': 1}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns

boxplot = df.boxplot(column=['A1x', 'A1y', 'A1z'])
```

If you do not import matplotlib in your code it'll give you an error like- ImportError: matplotlib is required for plotting when the default backend "matplotlib" is selected.

Comment: Yes sorry, I just put a single row just to show the content of the columns, but I'm working with different size dataframe (from 50 rows up to milions). Unfortunally I alredy made both the import so I can assume that this is not the cause.

Comment: if the solution worked for you,(worked for me) please accept it

Comment: It didn't work for me (also I was already using both import in my code). I still get the error `KeyError: "None of [Index(['A1x', 'A1y', 'A1z'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"`

Comment: this means your columns are not there in the dataframe. Could you show a bit of code like how the dataframe is being created?

Comment: It's not possible since I am loading different types of dataframes that must be rebuilded in a "standard" way. The code it's too long to be posted here. Moreover I am sure that the columns are in the dataframe since I can see them using df['name of the column']. The only problem is inside boxplot, which for some reason can't see them

Comment: you could show the way youre defining your boxplot

Comment: I just added it in the main post

Answer (score 0):

Way too late but I had a similar problem:
Check whether the columns you're plotting in the boxplot are numeric and not of 'object' type. Try converting the three columns explicitly into float using `.astype('float')`